# GitHub actions self-runner incorrect workspace paths

Tags: github, github-actions

When GitHub action is started with original github ubuntu-latest runner, all workspace paths are correct:

```
/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject (pwd path after start action)
/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject ${{ github.workspace }}
/home/runner/work/myproject ${{ github.runner }}
/home/runner/home $HOME
```

But when I run again the same action with `self-runner` and `container: ubuntu:latest` the paths are wrong:

```
/__w/myproject/myproject (pwd path after start action)
/home/user/myproject-runner/_work/myproject/myproject ${{ github.workspace }} WRONG PATH
/home/user/myproject-runner/_work/myproject ${{ github.runner }} WRONG PATH
/github/home $HOME ALSO DIFFERENT PATH
```

In all action steps the paths variables returns bad values. But when I used `${{ github.workspace }}` inside upload artifacts `actions/upload-artifact@v3` step, `workspace` will return correct value `/__w/myproject/myproject`.

Is it possible to solve that wrong paths, when action is running in self-runner? Is it something wrong with self-runner or yml action file?

```
name: Test
run-name: Test
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
env:
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND: "noninteractive"
  BUILD_NUMBER: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}-${{ github.sha }}
  TAR_FILENAME: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}-${{ github.sha }}.tar.gz
  BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
  TMP: /tmp

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    timeout-minutes: 60
    container: ubuntu:latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: "Print environment variables"
        run: |
          printenv
      - name: "Show list of files"
        run: |
          pwd #/__w/myproject/myproject
          echo ${{ github.workspace }} #/home/user/myproject-runner/_work/myproject/myproject
          echo ${{ runner.workspace }} #/home/user/myproject-runner/_work/myproject
          echo $HOME/home #/github/home
      - name: "Upload tar.gz file"
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: artifacts
          path: ${{ runner.workspace }}
          retention-days: 1
          if-no-files-found: error
```